# Django: Ajax data changes when Django gets it

Tags: django, ajax, datatable

Something weird is happening to me and I don't know why:

I have this data that I want to send throught ajax to django:

```
const params = {
    "status__in":['pendant','confirmed'],
    "access_date__year":2020,
    "access_date__month":05,
    "billable":true
}
```

I use datatable to creat a table with the data that I receive, this is the ajax options for datatable:

```
const ajax_options = {
    ajax: {
        url:get_consumptions_url,
        data: params
    }
}
```

Then I get the ajax params with this code:

```
ajax_data = request.GET.dict()
```

SO before trying to add an array to my params everything worked fine but when I check the ajax params debugging in python I get this:

```
{
'access_date__month': '10', 
'access_date__year': '2020', 
'billable': 'true', 
'status__in[]': 'confirmed'
}
```

Check "status__in" it completly changed from that I had in my params.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

When value of the parameter in ajax call is an array it is treated as a list in the POST in Django request, and you should use `getlist` to access the list. Please see [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) for more info.

Comment: It's working but why using a method like request.GET.dict() does return only the last value of the array? I mean, with .dict I get all the values in the request, but in the status case I get only the last element as a string. It's so weird

Comment: @AngelQuesada please look through [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/1130). There more about it.